# How to get attribute values of multiple nodes in xpath with just xmllint?

Tags: xpath

I want to query the names of all the persons in the test.xml below.

```
<body>
<person name="abc"></person>
<person name="def"></person>
<person name="ghi"></person>
</body>
```

### basic query

This has the problem of including "name", which I don't want.

```
$ xmllint --xpath '//body/person/@name' test.xml`
 name="abc"
 name="def"
 name="ghi"
```

### string function

Using the string function, I only get one result.

```
$ xmllint --xpath 'string(//body/person/@name)' test.xml
abc
```

### sed and grep

This works but looks needlessly complicated to me.

```
xmllint --xpath '//body/person/@name' test.xml | grep -o '"\([^"]*\)"' | sed 's|"||g'
abc
def
ghi
```

### Question

Is it possible to get multiple values without the attribute name and without using another tool like grep?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about `xmllint`, but `xmlstarlet` can do it:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -v 'body/person/@name' test.xml
```

Output:

```
abc                                  
def
ghi
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and end up using an xslt instead of an xpath

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version = "1.0" xmlns:xsl = "http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="//body/person[@name]">
    <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
    <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text> <!-- line break -->
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).